# How to programmatically split image from different color

Tags: image, colors, crop, image-recognition

I need to pro grammatically split this image [Image](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e0/6c/63/e06c631a76b14f49642a83ea33d810e7.jpg) in two images (top and bottom images) divide by the grey rectangle  in the center

Is there any recognition API to do this or is this possible to do that with any common programming language like C# ?

Comment: Yes it's _"possible to do that with any common programming language"_ that understands pixels (bitmap data). Just use `For` loops, in the bitmap take first pixel and travel downwards (along bmpData height) looking to hit a grey pixel of exact same value as you want. If `isMatch == true` then `Check every pixel along this scanline's width to see if all consistently same value (eg: grey)` if also true you have found boundary of top image area to extract, Now back to going downwards, you expect more grey pixels so check until **not** true. from here downwards  to end is 2nd half to extract.

Comment: PS: Try it with JavaScript (using Canvas API) since that way others can just check/test your code effort via web link to advise you. `For` loop logic would be the same when re-doing it in C#...